# Arranging Vector Outputs from multiple string variables

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

This is an assignment I am attempting to work on where I am attempting to create a program that asks for a books title, its author, and its date of publication, before displaying all inputs at the end. My primary obstacle is trying to get everything to display in a somewhat decent way, with additional text written to clarify the information properly.

It should look like this:

```
Title: Great Expectations     Fahrenheit 451       Animal Farm 
Author:   Charles Dickens       Ray Bradbury     George Orwell
Date:                1824               1956              1948
```

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int i=0;
  int n;
  string bookTitle;
  string bookAuthor;
  string bookDate;
  vector<string> Title;
  vector<string> Author;
  vector<string> Date;

  cout << "Enter the Number of Books: ";
  cin >> n;
  cin.ignore();
  for (i; i < n; i++)
    {
      cout << "Type the Book's Title: ";
      getline (cin, bookTitle);
      Title.push_back(bookTitle);
      cout << "Type the Book's Author: ";
      getline (cin, bookAuthor);
      Author.push_back(bookAuthor);
      cout << "Type the Book's Date: ";
      getline (cin, bookDate);
      Date.push_back(bookDate);
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The Titles: ";
    for (auto it = Title.begin(); it != Title.end(); ++it) {
    cout << *it << " ";
}
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Written by: ";
    for (auto ib = Author.begin(); ib != Author.end(); ++ib) {
cout << *ib << " ";
}
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Written in: ";
    for (auto ic = Date.begin(); ic != Date.end(); ++ic) {
cout << *ic << " ";
}
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead, make a book structure of three strings, then a vector of this book structure. It will be easier.

Comment: https://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~hutchins/csci241/output.htm is about cout format, that is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

First, let's organize your code a bit, by storing each book in a structure:

```
struct Book {
    string title;
    string author;
    string date;
};

vector<Book> books;
```

Read them like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Book book;
    getline (cin, book.title);
    getline (cin, book.author);
    getline (cin, book.date);
    books.push_back(book);
}
```

For each book, you can store a useful column width for your output. To keep it simple, only the book's title and author are considered when choosing the column width:

```
vector<int> widths;
int padding = 2;
for (const Book& book : books)
{
    widths.push_back(padding + std::max(book.title.size(), book.author.size()));
}
```

Now, use `std::setw` from `<iomanip>` to set the appropriate column width for each book:

```
cout << "The Titles: ";
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << std::setw(widths[i]) << books[i].title;
}
cout << endl;

cout << "Written by: ";
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << std::setw(widths[i]) << books[i].author;
}
cout << endl;

cout << "Written in: ";
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << std::setw(widths[i]) << books[i].date;
}
cout << endl;
```

Output:

```
The Titles:   Great Expectations  Fahrenheit 451    Animal Farm
Written by:      Charles Dickens    Ray Bradbury  George Orwell
Written in:                 1824            1956           1948
```

Comment: I keep getting an error message saying there is no pushback defined in the Book struct. what is being called in the library.pushback(book)?

Comment: Whatever code you wrote, it isn't correctly adapted from my answer. Firstly, "library" is not a `Book`. It would be a vector. And `pushback` is a non-existent function on a vector.

Comment: As I understand, the default positioning for strings is right-justified, so I omitted it. If it's really needed, it only should be applied once (_e.g._ before the output loops). It does not need to be called every time like `std::setw`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the std::setw() function within the  library to set a consistent field width to format the output neatly.

For example:

```
cout << setw(WIDTH) << *it << " ";
```